# How to complete rwd picture requirements without adding HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a project whose original screen structure is like the program example I attached!

Now the design draft requires that the original yellow block must appear below the green block on mobile devices, but my original HTML It is already arranged like this. I feel that if it is difficult to implement such a screen on a mobile device, I don't know how to accomplish such a screen change through css without adding HTML?

```css
.demo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.demo .main {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: #FBD148;
}
.demo .main .article {
  background-color: #49FF00;
  height: 200px;
}
.demo .main .reply {
  background-color: #3DB2FF;
  height: 200px;
}
.demo .about {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #FBFF00;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="main">
       <div class="article">article</div>
       <div class="reply">reply</div>
  </div>
  <div class="about">about</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: TBH *stuffing* the "about" inbetween the "article" and "reply" seems a really bad design decision.  But that depends on what the "about" is actually "about" - the right-side panel and html makes it look like it's about the page rather than that specific article (otherwise it would be in the .main div).

Comment: In fact, I just made an example. The yellow block in the real project is not about but recommended articles~

Comment: A very strange layout and i suppose you can't achieve the same result as a picture with flexbox. In this case, the `display:grid` is shine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solve this, the better way is to use `display: grid` in **demo** and **main** classes. The **demo** class will have two columns and two rows. In **main** will has only auto rows. With **@media** query we are redefine grid colums and rows in the **demo** and place the *yellow* element between *green* and *blue*.

```css
:root {
  --height: 200px;
}

.demo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, var(--height));
}

.demo .main {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: var(--height);
  background-color: #fbd148;
}

.demo .main .article {
  background-color: #49ff00;
}

.demo .main .reply {
  background-color: #3db2ff;
}

.demo .about {
  background-color: #fbff00;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .demo {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, var(--height));
  }
  .about {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  .reply {
    grid-row: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="article">article</div>
    <div class="reply">reply</div>
  </div>
  <div class="about">about</div>
</div>
```